# SASS :first-child not working selector

Tags: css, sass

`caution__item class` `first-child` not working. Help Me please.
Why **sass first-child** not working ?

```
.caution {
    &__item {
        border-radius: 3px;

        @include max-screen($screen-sm-max) {
            border-radius: 0;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;

            &:first-child {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }

            &:last-child {
                background: red;
                padding-bottom: 50px;
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `mixin` (inside or outside the scope, as you prefer) and then call it (with an argument) inside the scope

> [Sassmeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/12a9aa78b1c2fda2456fb20ab9de38ca)

```
.caution {
    &__item {
        @mixin max-screen($screen-sm-max) {
            border-radius: 0;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;

            &:first-child {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }

            &:last-child {
                background: red;
                padding-bottom: 50px;
            }
        }

        border-radius: 3px;
        @include max-screen(...);
    }
}
```

Note that you're not using the parameter `$screen-sm-max` inside the mixin but since you expect an argument you need to pass it (or an error will be raised "*Mixin max-screen is missing argument $screen-sm-max*")